# how to make GRUB find modules on multiboot Linux LiveUSB?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb-drive, live-usb

### background

*(skip to header=*`problem` *if you're expert on LiveUSBs, ISOs, GRUB2, etc)*

I'm setting up a multiboot/multiISO Linux LiveUSB as detailed [here](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/install_resizable_encrypted_lmde/src/HEAD/create_LMDE_liveUSB.rst), which I intend for use on multiple hosts (I.e., any arbitrary PC I decide I need to boot). The process seems straightforward:

1. Setup your [development host](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/install_resizable_encrypted_lmde/src/HEAD/create_LMDE_liveUSB.rst#rst-header-preparation): I.e., the box you'll use to create your LiveUSB, not that you'll boot with the LiveUSB.
2. Get/make a USB drive that

   1. is sufficiently large for all the ISOs you want to boot
   2. is bootable
   3. has [GRUB2 installed](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/install_resizable_encrypted_lmde/src/HEAD/create_LMDE_liveUSB.rst#rst-header-install-grub2-on-target)
3. Put desired ISOs on it, in an easily-specified location.
4. Edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

   1. Set global variables @ top (i.e., above the `menuentry`s), esp `root`
   2. Create one or more `menuentry`s for each ISO.

The main problem is, for each ISO, creating one or more `menuentry`s that appropriately boots it. This seems straightforward:

1. [Mount the ISO](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/install_resizable_encrypted_lmde/src/HEAD/create_LMDE_liveUSB.rst#rst-header-inspect-internal-structure-of-isos):

   1. Inspect the ISO's structure. Get its paths to its `grub.cfg`, `initrd*`, `vmlinuz` (or whatever it calls its GRUB config, initial RAMdisk image, and kernel image)
   2. Copy from the ISO's `grub.cfg` to your `menuentry`(s)
2. [Make each `menuentry`](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/install_resizable_encrypted_lmde/src/HEAD/create_LMDE_liveUSB.rst#rst-header-create-target-grub-cfg)

   1. set the boottime path to the ISO
   2. create a `loopback` device using the ISO
   3. use a path to the loopback device instead of the path given in the ISO's `grub.cfg`, e.g.,

      1. `initrd /casper/initrd.lz` -> `initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz`
      2. `linux /live/vmlinuz` -> `linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz`
3. Test your LiveUSB:

   1. While still mounted on your development host: [`grub-script-check`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/latest/en/man1/grub-script-check.1.html) for mental health :-)
   2. `umount` from your development host
   3. for each test host:

      1. attach to powered-down test host
      2. boot!

### problem

Many ISOs have `grub.cfg`s that want to configure video before doing the "real" boot. They all do it slightly differently, so I put each ISO's video code inside its `menuentry`(s). However the ISO `grub.cfg`s I've worked with so far seem to do it more-or-less like this:

```
if loadfont /path/to/font/file ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  insmod efi_gop
  insmod efi_uga
  insmod gfxterm
  terminal_output gfxterm
fi
# usually followed by more menu and background tweaking
```

The good news is, I *can* determine the boottime path to the fontfile--i.e., I can make `loadfont` happy. The bad news is, once inside the `if` block,

- only 1 of the modules loads.
- I get the same problem with ISOs that use Casper (e.g., Ubuntu-based Mint, LMDE1) or Debian Live (e.g., Clonezilla, LMDE2).

How do I make GRUB find **all** the modules?

#### example code

Note that Clonezilla's in-ISO `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` just forwards to its `/EFI/boot/grub.cfg`:

```
# This file is for compatibility to Ubuntu Linux's uEFI secure boot. 
# The real config file for grub is /EFI/boot/grub.cfg.
configfile /EFI/boot/grub.cfg
```

My LiveUSB's `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (outside of all the ISOs) contains code like

```
# isofile_abspath==path to the ISO from the root of my LiveUSB.
set isofile_abspath='/ISOs/clonezilla-live-2.4.2-10-amd64.iso'
set root=(hd0,1)
loopback loop ($root)$isofile_abspath
...
set clonezilla_prefix='(loop)/EFI/boot'
...
set loadfont_fp="$clonezilla_prefix/unicode.pf2"
echo -e "About to 'loadfont $loadfont_fp' ..."
if loadfont "$loadfont_fp" ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  echo -e 'about to `insmod efi_gop` ...'
  insmod efi_gop
  echo -e 'about to `insmod efi_uga` ...'
  insmod efi_uga
  echo -e 'about to `insmod gfxterm` ...'
  insmod gfxterm
  echo -e 'about to `terminal_output gfxterm` ...'
  terminal_output gfxterm
fi
echo -e 'Done loadfont.'
```

Results at boottime:

```
About to 'loadfont (loop)/EFI/boot/unicode.pf2' ...
about to `insmod efi_gop` ...
error: file not found.
about to `insmod efi_uga` ...
error: file not found.
about to `insmod gfxterm` ...
about to `terminal_output gfxterm` ...
error: no suitable mode found
Done loadfont.
```